# After level 60 do we get gold instead of exp?

Tags: diablo-iii

It seems we do, for completing quests. What about killing monsters?

Comment: You don't get xp for killing monsters. I *seem* to have got a popup of 30k gold for 60k xp once; but I'm beginning to think I imagined it - unless there is actually a reward system for idiots who still read books etc. ;)

Comment: @Alok at level 60 books end up only giving gold.  You probably imaged and hope that you were going to level to 61 :).  I try to read all the books I can so I can get more achievement points lol. :P

Comment: @Falcon165o: I specifically did **not** expect that xp would be useful in any way at lvl 60. But as I said, it was a single brief message that I haven't seen again; didn't even make a question because I could be just hallucinating - but its relevant for this discussion hence mentioned it.

Comment: @Alok :) I know I was only making a joke out of it.  If you made it to level 61 you better believe everyone else would be jealous!

Comment: @Falcon165o: Oh, I think my original comment isn't clear - the message seemed to imply that I was getting gold *instead* of xp (as opposed to it being completely wasted)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## Post 1.0.4

[Patch 1.0.4](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/6368188147) introduced a new level system for level 60s called [Paragon Levels](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/6968517/Introducing_the_Paragon_System-8_20_2012).  There are 100 Paragon Levels.  Killing monsters and completing Combat Challenge Streaks (Killing Blows, Massacres, etc) will award EXP towards Paragon Levels. Leveling up will give you more core stats (just like regular leveling up) along with +3% MF and +3% Gold Find per Paragon Level.  You also get a new border around your char that displays your Paragon Level to brag to your friends.

## Pre 1.0.4

When you gain level 60, all exp is gone.  Killing things will no longer give you XP, items and gold.  It will just give you items and gold as usual.  Quests will only give you gold instead of XP and gold.  The nicest thing about level 60 is the [Nephalem Valor](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Nephalem_Valor) which increases your gold and magic find at level 60 every time an elite mob is killed.  Each buff gives you 15% more gold find and magic find so it stacks to a max of 75.  This stacks up to 5 times and will last 30 minutes from your last elite kill, assuming you do not change any skills on your character and remain in the same game and act.

So in short no, XP just disappears and gold remains the same as the other levels.  Think of it this way, All XP gained at level 60 is now 0.  Nothing else changes EXP wise.

Comment: It only lasts 30 minutes, actually.

Comment: That was a typo on my end.  I fixed it.  Thank you for noticing it!

Comment: Probably should update this to talk about Paragon levels now.

Answer (score 7):

From my experience, it seems like all the XP rewards are just not there - you don't get additional gold from killing monsters, earning bonuses (destruction, massacre, etc) or completing quests, the XP rewards are just gone.

You do gain access to the Nephalem Valor buff, which increases your gold and magic find as you kill champion and elite monster packs, however.

Answer (score 5):

No, The gold will drop as it normally does.

You just don't get any exp for killing monsters the drops are still the same.

But You'll still get gold from quests.

If you find those log books and such you notice there is a +exp that pops up when you grab it but it is a lie and you get no exp from it. You just get to hear the beautiful recording.

Comment: I'm not seeing any extra gold from quests, do you have a source for this?

Comment: @bwarner Finish a quest and it will give you gold for doing it. Thats what I mean by extra gold.

Comment: @Samjus But it isn't "extra".  You always get gold for completing quests, and it is the same at level 60 as it is at other levels.

Comment: @bwarner I think your idea of extra is different than my idea of extra.  That gold for completing a quest is always extra gold. It's extra because it's like getting a tip while being a server. You get your base pay which is the drop from monsters and the tip is the gold from doing the quest.

Comment: I agree with @bwarner that a standard quest reward isn't 'extra' stuff.

Comment: I deleted the extra part just to avoid any confusion :)